Trouble with plot graphs
I try to compile this example for plotting graphs: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/drawing-graphs/
But, if I compile in TexWorks (pdfLatex or Overleaf)
% Drawing a graph using the PG 3.0 graphdrawing library
% Author: Mark Wibrow
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=0.75cm}]
\graph [tree layout, grow=down, fresh nodes, level distance=0.5in, sibling distance=0.5in]
    {
        4 -> { 
          3 -> { 1 -> { 5, " " }, 2,2 },
          3 -> { 1, 2, 2 },
          3 -> { 1, 2, 2 }
        } 
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I get such errors:
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/graphs/grow', to which you passed 'down', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/graph drawing/anchor at', to which you passed '(\tikz@lastx ,\tikz@lasty )', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/graphs/sibling distance', to which you passed '0.5in', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/graphs/tree layout' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/graphs/level distance', to which you passed '0.5in', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Graphs that I will expect see:

But I get with errors:

I assume that it is necessary to use LuaLatex, but the fact is that there are many good examples on the portal, and the layout is done using pdfLatex

It seems I misunderstood your question. I deleted my answer.

The text above the code on Texample explicitly states that Lualatex is required for that example, as does the manual for the graphdrawing library.
